# Is it possible to use node.js for distributed computations/work?

Tags: node.js, distributed-computing

Say I needed to do the following functions across a lot of data (for the sake of simplicity let's say each piece of data was a random word and there are billions of words)

1) lowercase the word (let's say this take 5ms)

2) lookup the word in a key/val dictionary and transform the word to the val (100ms)

3) save the (new) word/val to a remote system (1000ms)

So I might build a system that divides the work into 3 buckets to balance all operations across the assembly line consisting of 5 nodes to handle bucket 1, 20 nodes to handle bucket 2, and 200 nodes to handle bucket 3.

Is this something that could be done in node.js?  That is, can I spin up 'n' number of nodes tasked to do a particular function across k machines?

note: more than likely I would have the node.js node execute some (dynamic) command objects that are coded to do functions 1, 2, 3.

edit:  Please note my example was completely fabricated (both function and times).  I wanted to provide some concrete example but the gist of what I was asking is if node.js would be a good framework for creating mini distributed execution engines that could do some measure of work based on programmable functions (say through scriptable js). Thus, could I deploy n instances of node.js processes across several machines to collaborate on executing my examples?

given a large data set, 5 instances works on function 1 and delivers it to 20 instances to work on function 2 and delivers it to 100 instances to work on function 3 (per my examples)

Answer (score 0):

great question. I, along with likely many, have pondered this at some point.

In Javascript, executing functions doesn't usually take long at all. It may seem like it sometimes, but it's often stuff like logging to the console that takes a few milliseconds.

I took your example and developed a bit of code around it:

```
var valStore = {
    hello: 'world'
};

var word = 'HELLO';
var start = new Date().getTime();

word = word.toLowerCase();
var val = valStore[word];

var end = new Date().getTime();

console.log(val);
console.log(end - start);
```

Lowercase the word: **0ms** 
Look up the word in a key/val dictionary: **0ms** 
Save the word to a remote system: **probably about 100ms**, but that doesn't matter.

As you can see, the functions literally take less than a millisecond to execute. Of course, these are simple, non-computationally intensive functions. If you had a function that would take longer than 500ms to execute, that's when I would start to consider offloading it **to another thread.**

The whole idea behind Node.js stems from the fact that I/O operations take a considerably long time to execute, when compared to cpu-bound tasks.

For reference (In CPU Cycles): 
L1 cache: **3** cycles 
L2 cache: **14** cycles 
RAM:      **250** cycles 
Disk:     **41,000,000** cycles 
Network:  **240,000,000** cycles

Node.js attempts to solve this I/O problem by not waiting to hear back from a disk/network before it starts to executing more tasks. This is possible because of the Javascript event loop, which stacks up a bunch of functions to execute ahead of time.

Here is a great video by Philip Roberts explaining the event loop in detail:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ

Callbacks/Promises play a big part in this 'not waiting', because now instead of having to wait for a response from the server, we can access the RAM 960,000 (240,000,000 / 250) times and not waste any CPU cycles. When the server finally does **'call us back'** persay, we know what to do because of the callback function we made earlier. This callback function maintains the same scope as the function in which it was made for, so we can pretend (to say the least) like it's the original function that called it, just executed a later time.

Anyways, using your example we could convert a ton of words, do a bunch of lookups, and make a bunch of requests to the remote system all on the same server without much hassle. In fact, it might make more sense to have a bunch of machines doing all three things simultaneously. That would be a more plausible way to approach the distributed system architecture you're after.

A great way to do this would be through Microservices, linked is an introductory talk by Matt Smith:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Drs4e_Z5_70

For the dynamic aspect, you would likely want Express.js to help you craft some HTTP API Endpoints for the various functions you would like to perform.

Happy Coding!

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I edited my request to clarify it more as it seemed that some of your response may have addressed a part of my question that was meant to illustrate a larger design issue I was pondering.